# change the file name dynamically in SELECT * INTO XLSX('cities.xlsx',{headers:true}) FROM ?

Tags: javascript, excel, export, alasql

I'm using this function to sort and export data to excel

```
window.exportData = function () {
     data.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.destino - b.destino;
        });
     alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX('cities.xlsx',{headers:true}) FROM ? ",  [data]);
```

it works well. I need to change the name 'cities.xlsx' for a name like, for example,

var filename = 'cities'+variable+'.xlsx';

and obtain

alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX("filename",{headers:true}) FROM ? ",[data]);

in order to avoid confusions with saved files in excel.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL query as usual JavaScript string, like below:

```
 alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX('"+filename+"',{headers:true}) FROM ? ",  [data]);
```

Comment: var filename = 'cities'+h+g+'.xlsx';
         alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX('"filename"',{headers:true}) FROM ? ",[data]);

Comment: I have this variable: var filename = 'puertos'+h+g+'.xlsx'; what do I have to write in the blank
         alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX(                ,{headers:true}) FROM ? ",[data]); because I have tried many variants but  it doesn't work.

Comment: I got the solution: window.exportData = function () {
       data.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.destino - b.destino;
   });
         var filename = 'puertos'+h+g+'.xlsx';
         alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX('"+filename+"',{headers:true}) FROM ? ",[data]);
         data.length = 0;
      } I made a mistake with the filename.

Answer (score 0):

var filename = 'myFile.xlsx';

alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX( ? ,{headers:true}) FROM ? ",  [filename, data]);

I think this is the better solution like the way in sql world.